# Trouble with or, and, and not in if statments in Python

Tags: python

For some reason it always passes everything through.

```
if (keyphrase or keyphrase2 in comment.body) and ("Proof" or "proof" or "roof" or "Roof" or "woof" or "Woof" not in comment.body):
#do stuff
```

I'm new to Python sorry.

Comment: which sample output will not pass your condition? Be more specific about your asking.

Comment: Can u explain more about the context you are doing?

Comment: `x or y in z` is not the correct way to check for multiple conditions.  You have to spell out each condition fully, like so: `x in z or y in z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `any` and `all` with generator expressions to test multiple values for membership:

```
if any(k in comment.body for k in (keyphrase, keyphrase2)) and all(k not in comment.body for k in ("Proof", "proof", "roof", "Roof", "woof", "Woof")):
```

Answer (score 1):

You may expect:

```
if (x or y in z):
```

To be the same as:

```
if (x in z) or (y in z):
```

But in reality it's:

```
if (x) or (y in z):
```

So any True-like value of `x` will allow you to enter the `if` block body.

There are a few options to get what it seems like you're looking for, one is the `any` function and a generator expression):

```
if any(thing in z for thing in [x,y])
```